# Is it bad practice to write methods that start with "get" when they aren't getters?

Tags: java, oop, syntax, getter-setter

I was just curious since I'm used to objC where we use dot notation to call a getter, so when a method begins with get, it doesn't necessarily have anything to do with instance variables.

In java, would it be bad practice then to write methods that start with "get" when they aren't getters?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to?

Comment: don't use `get` for not getters unless you absolutely have to

Comment: Better to use "create" or "fetch" if it's not a true getter

Answer (score 3):

Using the prefix `get` for methods that serve a purpose greater than a simple `getter` can be misleading since the method may have unintended consequences not expected by the caller.

It would be a better practice to extract the additional functionality into a new method that's name portrays its intentions.

Answer (score 3):

Although the name of a getter must start with `get` according to the JavaBeans conventions, not all names that start in `get` must represent "dumb" getters, i.e. ones backed by a simple variable. If a method gets something, even a calculated thing that is associated with your object, giving it a name that starts in `get` is entirely appropriate.

Here is an example of a "get" method that does not represent a variable-backed property:

```
public class Person {
    private Date dob;
    // DOB is a "classic" property
    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    // Although ageInYears is a calculated property,
    // a name that starts in "get" is appropriate for it.
    int getAgeInYears() {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        now.setTime(new Date());
        Calendar old = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        old.setTime(dob);
        int diff = now.get(YEAR) - old.get(YEAR);
        if (old.get(MONTH) > now.get(MONTH) || 
        (old.get(MONTH) == now.get(MONTH) && old.get(DATE) > now.get(DATE))) {
            diff--;
        }
        return diff;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of APIs having `get` for either factory methods, facade, reflection or etc. It's absolutely unreasonable to restrict/avoid `get` prefix just only because getters *happen* to start with `get`. Moreover, factory pattern APIs, in most cases, have exactly `get` prefixes. [This](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)) is just one example of abovementioned.

Answer (score 2):

It will not end the world if you do so, but think about it from someone who is going to look at your code 5 years from now. Personally I would NOT use get for methods which are not actually getters. you can use fetch if you want. But just a personal preference.

have a look at this blog.

http://blog.joda.org/2011/08/common-java-method-names.html

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how you use it unless it makes the code confusing or misleading name your methods however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the answer is yes. Most programmers in Java are used to getters as 
methods which return the value of a private field.

As "get" is very general for a method name, prefer a more precise one that either tells you something about the intention (the question "why") or the algorithm (the question "how").
sortNames(...) or applyQuicksort(...) are much better than getPhoneBook().
Also, findNumberForName(...) is much better than getNumber(...).
"Find" indicates that it has a complexity of O(log(n)) or O(n) but not O(1) as it is usual for getters.

Sometimes you need or you want to keep the name very general.
I always use "provide" then instead of "get" to avoid confusion.